# how to use TCP monitor without target port(Using target Url)

Tags: tcp

I need to use tcp monitor to check my request. 
When my url is

> localhost:9090/RestToRest/rest2rest

. Then I know 9090 is **target port** under the Listener.

But when use url as

> http://postman-echo.com/post

what is the **target port**? . Or can we use tcp monitor with another way to do this

Comment: The default port for HTTP is 80.

Answer (score 0):

Try with bellow answer

> Target Hostname http://postman-echo.com
>
> Port - 80